# Optimize MySQL Query - with a join within a sub select within a join

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

Okay, so there is a slow query in SugarCRM that is causing significant issues when it runs back to back to back..., etc..  I've pasted the query below and I'm looking to see if there is any expert out there that might know of a better way to structure this query so that it runs in a fraction of a second as opposed to the 2+ seconds it takes now.

```
SELECT acl_actions.id, 
   acl_actions.NAME, 
   acl_actions.category, 
   acl_actions.acltype, 
   acl_actions.aclaccess, 
   tt.access_override 
FROM   acl_actions 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT acl_roles_users.user_id, 
                     acl_roles_actions.action_id, 
                     acl_roles_actions.access_override 
              FROM   acl_roles_users 
                     LEFT JOIN acl_roles_actions acl_roles_actions 
                            ON acl_roles_actions.role_id = 
                               acl_roles_users.role_id 
                               AND acl_roles_actions.deleted = 0 
              WHERE  ( acl_roles_users.user_id = 
                       'XXXXXXXXX' ) 
                     AND ( acl_roles_users.deleted = 0 )) tt 
          ON tt.action_id = acl_actions.id 
WHERE  acl_actions.deleted = 0 
ORDER  BY acl_actions.category ASC, 
      acl_actions.NAME ASC;
```

Here's the results of EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table             | partitions | type | possible_keys                                                 | key                   | key_len | ref                                      | rows | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acl_actions       | NULL       | ref  | idx_del_category_name_acltype_aclaccess,idx_del_category_name | idx_del_category_name | 2       | const                                    | 3520 |   100.00 | Using index condition    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acl_roles_users   | NULL       | ref  | idx_acluser_id                                                | idx_acluser_id        | 145     | const                                    |    1 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | acl_roles_actions | NULL       | ref  | idx_acl_role_id,idx_del_override,idx_aclrole_action           | idx_del_override      | 147     | production.acl_roles_users.role_id,const |  312 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+----------+--------------------------+
```

CREATE TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE `acl_actions` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acltype` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aclaccess` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_aclaction_id_del` (`id`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_category_name` (`category`,`name`),
  KEY `idx_del_category_name_acltype_aclaccess` (`deleted`,`category`,`name`,`acltype`,`aclaccess`),
  KEY `idx_del_category_name` (`deleted`,`category`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

```
CREATE TABLE `acl_roles_users` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_aclrole_id` (`role_id`),
  KEY `idx_acluser_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `idx_aclrole_user` (`role_id`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

```
CREATE TABLE `acl_roles_actions` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `role_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `access_override` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_acl_role_id` (`role_id`),
  KEY `idx_acl_action_id` (`action_id`),
  KEY `idx_del_override` (`role_id`,`deleted`,`action_id`,`access_override`),
  KEY `idx_aclrole_action` (`role_id`,`action_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: For perfomance question you have to include [QUERY PLAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: I think by "QUERY PLAN" you mean to put the "EXPLAIN" output.  I've edited the question to include that.

Comment: Can you include some information about table sizes and what are the table index? The `CREATE TABLE`  DDL may be good enough

Comment: Well, I think I might have found a solution.  Running that subselect separately first, then making it part of the WHERE in the second select seems to take the query from ~2.5 seconds to ~0.02 seconds.

Comment: But then you have to run 2 queries and add the time for both, isn't?

Comment: Yes, but it seems to faster that way by a factor of about 100x's.

Comment: My point is you should be able to do it in a single query if the index are well set

Comment: Oh good point!  Do you have any suggestion for what those indexes should be based on the create table syntax I've edited into the OP?

Comment: In sugarcrm all the necessary indexes are already set for performance enhancement, So I personally like to do it in two queries and avoid to use sub-query.